# WP7 background audio resources are no longer available

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, media, background-audio

I'm using `BackgroundAudioPlayer` for my Windows Phone 7 music & video application. After I play some music, I play video using `MediaPlayerLauncher`, then press Back to return to my app. There whenever I use `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance`. I receive error "**The background audio resources are no longer available**".

[Someone on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/f1272e7c-e138-4d95-9ee2-0fb08309d2f4/) suggests using try/catch, but this is not a good idea, and can slow down the app.

Other suggests call `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close()` before launch `MediaPlayer`. However, when I play music, the agent load .dll again, which takes very much time.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Why is try/catch a bad idea???

Comment: @PaulAnnetts because it will slow down our app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you play a video after your audio the OS will definitely "terminate" your Background Audio Player. From your question it seems this is reproducible 100% of the time which would confirm this. Your only option is to restart the background audio player again after you have called `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close()`, and then played your video. Which as you said will require reloading your player DLL when you start the BAP.

**Update following up from comments**

If you aren't implementing a streaming audio agent but only an AudioPlayer agent there isn't a process for you to kill anyway. The OS spins up a process as and when it needs to get you to process an action (e.g.: user action, track ended, shutdown).

`BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close()` just makes sure that the OS releases those resources cleanly in a scenario such as the OP has.

To restart background audio, just call `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play()` again.

Comment: in my app, it works when I call Instance.Close() before launching MediaPlayer. When I play music, I see it loads .dlls. But as you mentioned "restart agent using Instance.Close()", so the agent should load .dlls right after I call Close() ?

Comment: Good point - Close() won't reload the DLLs. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, but what does Close() do? You said that the OS will terminate agent when I play video, so there's no need to call Close() ?

Comment: Close() will close the BAP more cleanly so you don't get exceptions thrown if you try accessing the old terminated  BAP instance

Comment: Close() terminates the BAP instance? or terminate the process it lives in? I see it reloads .dlls, so that it's the PROCESS that was killed ?

Comment: And how can I restart BackgroundAudioPlayer after Close called?
Please see this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769275/how-to-reuse-backgroundaudioplayer-after-close-method-called

Comment: @Yama moto: If you aren't implementing a Streaming audio agent but only an AudioPlayer agent there isn't a process for you to kill anyway. The OS spins up a process as and when it needs. I'll update the answer with this.