# AudioPlaybackagent - WP8

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, mediaelement, audio-playback-agent

In windows phone 8 application, I'm using AudioPlaybackagent to play a background audio.

I did the following scenario:

I play

```
  BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play(),
```

while the song is playing I called

```
  BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop()
```

then play another song using     mediaElement

The problem is that if I want to replay the first song usingBackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play()

it returns an exception

```
  The background audio resources are no longer available.
```

Comment: You are going to have to post more of your code. No one can help you with the info you have given so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play audio with the background agent, stop, and then play audio with the media element.  I belive you'll have to do:

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop()
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close()
```

Then attempt to play audio with the media element.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769275/how-to-reuse-backgroundaudioplayer-after-close-method-called